# The function does not see the email, the subject and text. Php and html contact form

Tags: php, html, email

Guys i have a problem on my site, i build a contact form and i write the php function. The problem is that the function does not see the email, subject and comments in the html file so i always return the error "Insert email or subject or comments". Here is the code of php and html. Thanks in advance.

```
       <?php

    $myemail  = "info@codaps.it";

    $email    = check_input($_POST['email'], "Inserisci la tua email");
    $subject  = check_input($_POST['subject'], "Inserisci l'oggetto per il quale ci scrivi");
    $comments = check_input($_POST['comments'], "Scrivi un breve messaggio");

    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
    {
        show_error("Indirizzo E-mail non valido!");
    }

    $message = "Ciao!

    Il tuo form di contatto è stato compilato da:

    E-mail: $email
    Oggetto: $subject

    Commenti:
    $comments

    Fine del messaggio!
    ";

    mail($myemail, $email, $subject, $message);

    header('Location: thanks.html');
    exit();

    function check_input($data, $problem='')
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
        {
            show_error($problem);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function show_error($myError)
    {
    ?>
        <html>
        <body>

        <b>Perfavore correggi i seguenti errori:</b><br />
        <?php echo $myError; ?>

        </body>
        </html>
    <?php
    exit();
    }
    ?>
/*html*\

`<div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="block">
                 <form action="php/contact.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" name="email"  class="form-control" placeholder="Indirizzo email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Oggetto">
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="block">
                    <form action="php/contact.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group-2">
                      <textarea name="comments" rows="3"  class="form-control" placeholder="Il tuo messaggio"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Invia">
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>`
```

Comment: So var_dump($_POST); at the begginning of the code give back and empty array for you?

Comment: Which of those _two_ forms are you actually submitting?

Comment: Also, OT, but "Perfavore" are two words: "Per favore".

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yes thanks typing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The submit button will submit the form it is in (containing only the `<textarea>`).

Inputs in a different form won't be included in the submitted data.

You need a **single** form element.

Comment: Ok now work. Except now I have to readjust all the page because the textarea it is not in the other column

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace:

```
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
```

by:

```
if (($problem != '') && (strlen($data) == 0))
```

in the `check_input()` function. To correct the operator precedence:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php